# iteration in for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

Here is my current code

```
dat= data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10,c=1:10,d=1:10,e=1:10)
for (i in 1:ncol(dat)) {
    print(interaction(##...what to write here?*...##))}
```

My for loop should do the following thing

First iteration:

```
 interaction(dat[,1],dat[,2])
```

second iteration :

```
interaction(dat[,1],dat[,2],dat[,3])
```

Third iteration

```
interaction(dat[,1],dat[,2],dat[,3],dat[,4])
```

etc...

I don't really mind whether the function is `interaction` or `sum` or whatever. It is the simple principle of the first loop. I had the same kinda trouble with aov(`what to write here?`) but I discovered the formula type of object that allowed me to write a formula depending on i( = the iterative object) .

Thank you.

Comment: I think this question needs some heavy clarification.  Anyone understand well enough to flesh it out?

Comment: I am even more confused now. Your question has nothing to do with `ggplot2`?

Comment: Indeed I confused everybody. Sorry about that ! I changed everything from my question including the title. Now I thing it will be easier to understand. My question should actually not be a hard one I guess !

Comment: Do you want to store these as columns of `dat`? Have you tried some code and run into problems?  What did that code look like?

Comment: @Justin I add some comment directly in my question above

Comment: For writing code, press 4 spaces and start typing. Don't use `>`. I've edited your code 3 times now. It should have been easier to spot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this will get you started...
In a `for loop`:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(dat)) {
  interaction(dat[,1:i])
}
```

You could also use one of the `apply` family:

```
lapply(2:ncol(dat), 
       function(x) interaction(dat[,1:x]))
```

But really, the best answer depends on how you plan to use these going forward.

Comment: Oh, I see we have exactly the same second solution so I will delete mine as you posted first. But I was wondering, why do you use `do.call`?

Comment: because I didn't test my answer and didn't remember if `interaction` took multiple columns.  If it didn't and wanted individual arguments, you would need `do.call`.